# call images from resources instead of urls in staggered grid view?

Tags: android, android-gridview, custom-adapter

what i have is open source staggered grid view adapter which build a nice dynamic grid view here is the main activity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private String urls[] = { 
            "http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6101/6853156632_6374976d38_c.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7232/6913504132_a0fce67a0e_c.jpg",
            "http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4133/5096108108_df62764fcc_b.jpg",
            "http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4074/4789681330_2e30dfcacb_b.jpg"};
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StaggeredGridView gridView = (StaggeredGridView) this.findViewById(R.id.staggeredGridView1);

        int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin);

        gridView.setItemMargin(margin); // set the GridView margin

        gridView.setPadding(margin, 0, margin, 0); // have the margin on the sides as well 

        StaggeredAdapter adapter = new StaggeredAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.id.imageView1, urls);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is the adapter code :

```
public class StaggeredAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private ImageLoader mLoader;

    public StaggeredAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.row_staggered_demo,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ScaleImageView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        mLoader.DisplayImage(getItem(position), holder.imageView);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ScaleImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

what i want to do is to call images from resources instead of links like this :

```
private int urls[] = { R.drawable.roller_blinds, R.drawable.zebra_blinds2,R.drawable.zebra_blinds,
            R.drawable.wooden_blinds,R.drawable.wooden2_blinds,R.drawable.office,R.drawable.motors,
            R.drawable.curtains_accessories
            };
```

and i have change the constructor in the adapter to this :

```
public StaggeredAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            int[] objects) {
```

but i keep see an error in this line :

```
super(context, textViewResourceId,objects);
```

why this is happening?? and how can i call my images from resources instead of links? what I've done wrong??

the error says :

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, int, int[]) is undefined
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem except I am using Glide to load images. Did you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to

```
ArrayAdapter(Context, int, int[])
```

since you are defining T to be String so the actual constructor that you have access to is

```
ArrayAdapter(Context, int, String[])
```

I hope it makes sense

Comment: so where can i found the actual one?

Comment: The actual constructor is like ArrayAdapter(Context, int, T[])</code> and T is defined when you  public class StaggeredAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<T>ave a look at generics in Java. It should make it more clear